# Android Asynchronous Http Client upgrade

Tags: android, http, asynchronous

I have a problem with Android Asynchronous Http Client (http://loopj.com/android-async-http/).
Until today I used the 1.4.6 version and my code (see below works without problem).

```
RestClient.get(MyUrl, null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "START", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Where RestClient is this:

```
public class RestClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.example.com/action.php?";

    private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
        return BASE_URL + relativeUrl;
    }
}
```

After upgrade Android Asynchronous Http Client library from 1.4.6 to 1.4.9 (the last) I get the error "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype" on Android Studio about onSuccess and onFailure methods.

Any ideas about whats is change on library? I have read the changelog but I cannot found a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The interface on those methods have changed.  You have:
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response)

public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable)

The updated interface is:
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response)

public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e)

Looks like it has changed from taking a String as an argument to using a byte array.  Probably to avoid making assumptions about the encoding of your strings.

Comment: This is right, but I'm using JsonHttpResponseHandler to get JSONObject response, so how the change affects my code?

Comment: Bit tough to put code in comments - but try replacing your version of onFailure and onSuccess with the updated function declaration I posted above.  Then comment out the code in the body of your function (for now).  Does your code compile?  After you get it compiling then you'll need to change the body of your function to handle the new interface.  Unfortunately the author of an API can change interfaces on a whim.  Though usually they give external programmers a head's up by making them deprecated and give you a period of time to use an overloaded function for you to transition to.